# Emit after cancellation in Kotlin flow

Tags: kotlin, cancellation, kotlin-flow

I have a more complex version of the following code:

```kotlin
val testFlow = flow {
    try {
        // Continually emit some values
    } catch (e: CancellationException) {
        // Wrap up and emit finished state value
    }
}
```

When I collect this testFlow, I never receive the finished state value. It is [documented](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/flow.html#flow-cancellation-checks) that the flow builder performs ensureActive checks before emitting values. In this link is also an example using `IntRange.asFlow` that does not check for cancellation before emitting values and showing that those values are continued to be collected.

Is there a way to make a custom kotlin flow emit a last value to be collected after the cancellation of the coroutine?

Here's a [Kotlin Playground example](https://pl.kotl.in/jLRvus-sN) (thanks @Tenfour04) showing differing behaviour of emit after cancel depending on how the flow is constructed. I just don't know how to get a flow that's able to emit after cancel that is not constructed by `IntRange.asFlow`.

Comment: You can’t emit if there’s a CancellationException because that means the flow is no longer being collected.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The IntRange.asFlow example shows that there seems to be a way to continue to collect after coroutine cancellation. Can you elaborate on where my misunderstanding is?

Comment: I don't see any examples of that on that page. There are examples of logging something after cancellation, but not emitting anything. When a coroutine is cancelled, it will stop all execution at its first opportunity (any suspend function call), so even if you have code in an `onCompletion` operator on your Flow, the `onCompletion` block will only execute code up to the first suspend function call it makes.

Comment: Did you take a look at the playground example I gave? The IntRange testFlow continues to emit values 4 and 5 even though the coroutine was cancelled when collecting value 3. 

If I understand correctly, flow cancellation is cooperative and the IntRange example does not cooperatively cancel itself immediately, even though it still seems to be emitting values (at least implicitly). 

Sorry to repeatedly ask. I don't seem to get the technical difference between the IntRange example and a custom flow using `flow {}` builder.

Comment: OK, I looked at it and I am very stumped. `IntRange.asFlow()` doesn't seem to cooperate with cancellation, even though if you look at the implementation, it uses a `flow` builder with `emit`, and if you rebuild the identical code directly, it *does* cooperate! See here: https://pl.kotl.in/KvFli_h59

Comment: Thanks a lot for hearing me out and greatly improving my playground sample. 
Tomorrow at work, I'll try to improve the wording and code sample of my question with your code and see if anyone has an answer for this.

Comment: `IntRange.asFlow` uses unsafeFlow as a flow builder which is defined [here](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/15815923970b5da2e9a1bd0d68293869341714c1/kotlinx-coroutines-core/common/src/flow/internal/SafeCollector.common.kt#L104).
See it working in my new [Kotlin playground](https://pl.kotl.in/Vrs5ypvKC). This explains why IntRange behaves differently, but doesn't solve my problem without using internal kotlinx.coroutines APIs.

Comment: So the IDE falsely shows `flow` instead of `unsafeFlow`, but if you hover it you can see that it's `unsafeFlow`. Very tricky! https://i.imgur.com/kCda5ti.png

Comment: If you ctrl+click it in android studio you can see that it brings you to unsafeFlow. I think they imported the unsafeFlow as flow at the top of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IntRange.asFlow` uses unsafeFlow internally which is defined as:

```
inline fun <T> unsafeFlow(crossinline block: suspend FlowCollector<T>.() -> Unit): Flow<T> {
    return object : Flow<T> {
        override suspend fun collect(collector: FlowCollector<T>) {
            collector.block()
        }
    }
}
```

Using unsafeFlow one can emit even in cancelled coroutines, even though this solution is quite a hack and I would like to replace it with a more officially supported version that does not require to access internal Kotlin Coroutine APIs.

Note: Emitting after cancellation only works when using

```
try {
    ...
} catch (e: CancellationException) {
    ...
}
```

and not using `unsafeFlow.catch {}`.

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering the same thing. I think one approach would be to use a StateFlow and generate values separately. That way you can call `.value` before (it also works if it is called after) cancelling the job.

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.delay
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.MutableStateFlow
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import kotlinx.coroutines.runBlocking

fun main(): Unit = runBlocking{
    val startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
    val elapsedTime = MutableStateFlow(0L)
    // generate values
    val job = launch {
        while (true){
            elapsedTime.value = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime
            delay(1000)
        }
    }
    // collect values
    launch {
        elapsedTime.collect{ println("$it milliseconds") }
    }
    // cancel job
    delay(2222)
    println("CANCELLING")
    elapsedTime.value = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime // emit before cancelling
    job.cancel()
    println("CANCELLED")
}
```

```
25 milliseconds
1027 milliseconds
2030 milliseconds
CANCELLING
CANCELLED
2251 milliseconds
```

Actually, the order doesn't matter since only the job generating values is cancelled, but not the collector.

Maybe MutableSharedFlow can be useful.

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.delay
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.MutableSharedFlow
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import kotlinx.coroutines.runBlocking

fun main(): Unit = runBlocking{
    // val flow1 = (1..10).asFlow()
    val range = (1..10)
    val flow1 = MutableSharedFlow<Int>(replay = range.count()) // since it is "hot", might need to replay values to new subscribers
    // generate values
    val job = launch {
        range.forEach{
            flow1.emit(it)
            delay(1000) // for testing, otherwise it would be complete before the collecting starts
        }
    }
    // collect values
    launch {
        flow1.collect{
            println(it)
            if(it == 3){
                job.cancel()
                flow1.emit(4)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
1
2
3
4
```